Nonfactors mvc grid retain column filters on refresh
The website I am working on displays a grid of currently in production items which we wish to reload every 5m to find any deletions/additions. However we don't want users to have to reapply filters/sorting every time that a new reload takes place. Is there a way to store these values in sessionStorage or the like and reapply them to the grid post reload?
Attached is the grid code:

<body onload="autoRefresh('First')"></body>

<div id="QueueTable">

    @(Html
        .Grid(Model.ProductionQueues)
        .Named("Production")
        .Build(columns =>
        {
            columns.Add().Encoded(false).RenderedAs(model => model.WOI_Visualisation == true ? Html.ActionLink("", "ViewPDF", new { fileName = model.pdfPath_WithRevision.Split(@"\").Last() },
            new { @class = "fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-2x", @style = model.styleClass != null ? "color:#73879C" : null }) : Html.Raw(""));

            columns.Add(model => model.WO_ID_Prefix).Titled("Work Order");
            columns.Add(model => model.WOI_ID).Titled("WO Item");
            columns.Add(model => model.BOM_DwgNo).Titled("Part");
            columns.Add(Model => Model.BOM_Description).Titled("Description");
            columns.Add(model => model.WO_RequiredByDateAsDate).Titled("Required By").Formatted("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}");
            columns.Add(model => model.companyName).Titled("Company Name");
            columns.Add(model => model.jobNumber).Titled("Job Number");
            columns.Add(model => model.JC_WBS).Titled("Jobcard");
            columns.Add(model => model.WO_TypeText).Titled("WO Type");
            columns.Add(model => model.sortPriorityInt).Titled("Priority");
        })
        .Empty("All submitted jobs complete").Filterable().Sortable().Pageable()
        .RowAttributed(model => new { @class = model.styleClass != null ? model.styleClass : null })
        ).

</div>

and the relevant javascript code that I have been working on:
let intervalID;
function autoRefresh(refreshTimer) {
    window.clearInterval(intervalID);

    var dropdown = document.getElementById("refreshTimer");

    if (refreshTimer != "Never" && refreshTimer != "First") {
        intervalID = window.setInterval(function () {
            getUpdates()
        }, refreshTimer)
    }
    else if (refreshTimer == "First" && sessionStorage.getItem("RefreshTimer")) {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem("RefreshTimer") != "Never" && sessionStorage.getItem("RefreshTimer") != "First") {
            intervalID = window.setInterval(function () {
                getUpdates();
            }, sessionStorage.getItem("RefreshTimer"))

            refreshTimer = sessionStorage.getItem("RefreshTimer");

            dropdown.value = sessionStorage.getItem("RefreshTimer");
        }
    }

    sessionStorage.removeItem("RefreshTimer");
    sessionStorage.setItem("RefreshTimer", refreshTimer);
}

function getUpdates() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Leaderboard/GetAll' + queue,
        data: "",
        success: function (msg) {
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert("failed");
        }
    })
}

